# Did 'v-html' would remove some css attrs when build?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

in dev I use `-webkit-box-orient: vertical;` and it is work, but it doesnt work in build environment. some code like this:

```
<div v-if="show" class="mystyle" v-html="text1"></div>
<div v-else class="mystyle cusstyle">{{text2}}</div>

.cusstyle {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

there are only three attrs remains in build environment and cant find `-webkit-box-orient: vertical;`